# start an activity after button click

Tags: android, android-activity

I want to start an activity only once after the application starts. I did this code:

```
Boolean isFirstRun = getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE)
            .getBoolean("isFirstRun", true);

    if (isFirstRun) {
        //show start activity

        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, FirstLaunch.class));
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "First Run", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
    }


       getSharedPreferences("PREFERENCE", MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                .putBoolean("isFirstRun", false).commit();
```

but it didn't work for the thing that I want. I want when I click on a button and  launch the activity. But the main activity launches

Comment: Rest in peace English.

Comment: @sajad Could you be more clear and elaborate what you are asking with some example

Comment: Be clear what u r asking?

Comment: If you found my answer useful, could you accept it? ;)

Answer (score 2):

To start an activity, you need to use intents. And you can call this when a button is clicked like so:

```
Button myButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MY_BUTTON);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.class, NextActivity.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
```

You can read more about starting activities [here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html).

Comment: this is correct for what op is asking. op I would recommend reading into android code a little deeper...